# Angular: Cascading data load in dynamic row

Tags: angular

In a dynamic row there is a product type drop down(Tipas) which is already loaded with the product types; so my concern is whenever a product type is selected a separate corresponding product list should be loaded in the product search text box(Produktas). When loaded product can be searched from the product list.

How could it be achieved?

[image: dynamic rows given here for reference]

Comment: So, when do you get the data for `Product List`? On component `Init` or when you select an item from the `Type` dropdown and then you fetch the list?

Comment: @Shuvo `Product List` is fetched when an item is selected from `Type` dropdown. However, `Product List` may vary as `Type` changes.

Comment: Okay, I get it. So, what is the issue now? Populating the `Product List` in the dropdown based on the `type` selected? Or implementing the `search` functionality in the `Product List` dropdown?

Comment: @Shuvo Populating the `Product List` and `search` functionality is working fine but my issue is cascading loading of `Product List` when there are multiple rows. I mean if a `type` is selected same `Product List` shows for all previous search-boxes in the multiple rows instead of being separate corresponding `Product List'.